# SSRS 2008 R2 domain user assigned for role but cannot access

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have SSRS 2008 R2 installed on my server and need to deploy report from Business Intelligence Studio at another computer which is in the same domain and under domain user (non-administrator).

First I get the error "Unsufficient permissions". Then I started Report Manager at the server (http://localhost/Reports/) and under Site Settings / Security added my domain user to both System Administrator and System Users roles, restarted the service, but still got the same error.

Then I created a folder in Report Manager and added domain user to all available roles for that (Browser, Publisher, etc.). After that it doesn't show that error in BIS but instead shows the login dialog (though I already logged as domain user in Windows). I enter login and password but it just asking it again and doing nothing.

Could you advice me how to enable access to the service or at least to some folder for non-administrator domain user?

**Update:** Tried to enter administrator login details to that login windows but it also just shown again.

Comment: it belongs to serverfault.com

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Not strictly - SSRS is a tool/technology used and deployed by programmers, therefore questions about it can still be on topic here.

Comment: I've gotten that when I had something wrong in my deploy properties.  Be sure your folder paths are using "/", and your target server URL is correct.  Check the reporting services configuration manager for verification.